# Combination of Matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

I have two matrices, one of which (Let's say matrix H) is 4x2 and the other one (matrix N) is 100x2.
I want to make a combination for every pair of N, containing every pair of H.

Basically, if my

```
H = [2 2; 2 4; 4 2; 4 4]
N = [1 1; 1 2; 1 3; ...; 
    10 8; 10 9; 10 10]
```

I would like to have a final matrix

```
M = [1 2 2 1; 1 2 4 1; 1 4 2 1; 1 4 4 1; 1 2 2 2; 1 2 4 2; ...; 10 4 4 10]
```

of a size 100x4 (because every pair of N will be multiplied |H|=4 times.)

So all the pairs of H matrix will be between all pairs of my N matrix.

I hope I am clear enough.

Comment: With H be 4x2 matrix and N be 10x2 matrix, shouldn't your final matrix be 40x4 instead of 100x4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the follwing syntax:

```
%calculates the Cartesian multipication of 1:size(h,1) and 1:size(N,1) 
sets = {1:size(H,1), 1:size(N,1)};
[hInds, nInds] = ndgrid(sets{:});

%generates the output matrix
outRes = [N( nInds(:),1),H( hInds(:),1),H( hInds(:),2),N( nInds(:),2)];
```

Partial results (displaying just the first rows of the output):

```
 outRes = 
 1     2     2     1
 1     2     4     1
 1     4     2     1
 1     4     4     1
 1     2     2     2
 1     2     4     2
 1     4     2     2
 1     4     4     2
 1     2     2     3
 1     2     4     3
 1     4     2     3
 1     4     4     3
 ...
```

Notice that if N is 4x2 and N is 10x2, the final matrix size will be 40x4 and not 100x4 as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. It works, and I meant 100x2 for |N|, sorry about that.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
H= [2 2; 2 4; 4 2; 4 4];
N= fix(100*(rand(10,2))) % Replace this with your N matrix

iter=0;
for i=1:10
for j=1:4
    iter=iter+1;
A(iter,:)=[N(i,1), H(j,1:2), N(i,2)];
end
end

A
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking anyway for a solution without a for loop, but this seems to be working, too.